# Kafka jdbc sink connector does not correct convert timestamp

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect

i have a schema

```
  {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "test",
      "namespace" : "test",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "time",
        "type": [ "null", {
          "type": "long",
          "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
        }]
      }, 
....
 {
        "name" : "time2",
        "type": ["null", {
          "type" :  "long",
          "logicaltype": "timestamp-millis"
        }]
      }
    }
```

But when kafka connector deserialize the data and create the sql insert i have the next error

```
column "time2" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type bigint
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO "test" ("time",  "time2")
VALUES  ('2018-2-2 20:14:45.507000 +0:0:0', 1517602485507)
```

it s strange because date and code is the same. Why the first date field "time" converts ok but in the second i have a problem?